# Как отследить input jquery autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, autocomplete

Ситуация заключается в следующем. Есть поисковая строка с автозаполнением значений. При вводе данных, пользователь получает подсказки из массива данных прописанных в файле JS.
Есть необходимость вывода выбранного текстового значения в span, после нажатия кнопки. В итоге текст вывести не получается, а лишь элемент самой строки либо его значение placeholder. Пытался реализовать через селекторы ById и TagName, не получается. Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать задуманное...

```
<script>
var button = document.getElementById("submit");
button.onclick = function() {
var p = document.getElementById("user-city");
var value = document.getElementById("myInput");
p.innerHTML = value.outerHTML;
}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Alex45678/k1q03ceb/10/

Comment: может потому что `span` не закрыт. И стоило как-то предоставить код, который можно править, а не гадать визуально

Comment: Может попробовать `elem.value` или `elem.val()`?

Comment: `span` закрыл, там дело именно в логике. Несколько дней уже пытаюсь разобраться. При добавлении значения в строку, формируются div блоки. Теперь код можно редактировать, залил на другой ресурс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, что там за логика, но если...

1. Добавить в конец `form target="_blank"`, чтоб текущая страница осталась не перезагруженной

```html
<form autocomplete="off" action="index.html" target="_blank">
```

2. Изменить вот это непонятно что :(

```js
//p.innerHTML = value.outerHTML;
p.innerHTML = value.value;
```

... то все там в `<span>` нормально устанавливается
https://jsfiddle.net/6rsk9e3c/

А каким образом отправить форму, это уже на усмотрение автора.

Comment: Да да да, всё дело в скрипте в котором была допущена ошибка банально по не знанию. Форму никуда не нужно отправлять, а всего лишь передавать значение input в класс span для дальнейшей логики)) Большое спасибо, что уделили время и исправили ошибку :)